I need help aligning elements on a web page

I have a webpage with the elements as shown in the attached image. What I want is for the titles to maintain the same size rectangular white background. if a title is too long it should be truncated with ellipses at the end. The title on the left should be the same size as the other 2 titles. The website link is https://glimafrika.com/. Any CSS provided to achieve that would be greatly appreciated.
